# iteration loop over nested lists for indexing an index variable to a data variable

Tags: r, data.table

In instructing over to iterate by a function:

```
input_list <- list (list(c(1,2,3),c(4,5,6)),list(c(7,8,9),c(10,11,12)))

# data.table :: CJ is a fast expand.grid
library ( data.table )
total_value <- 28

fun <- function (x) do.call (CJ , input_list[[x]]) # get all combinations
DT  <- lapply ( seq ( length ( input_list )) , fun )
fun <-  function (x)  DT[[x]] [rowSums (DT[[x]]) == total_value ] 
values  <-  lapply ( seq ( length ( DT )) , fun )

fun <- function (x) lapply(input_list[[x]],function(a)    data.table(a,seq_along (a)))
index_map <- lapply (seq(length(input_list)),fun)
fun <-  function(x) lapply (names (values[[x]]),function (b) c(b,sub("V", "index",b)))
nams <- lapply(seq(length(values)),fun)
fun <- function(x)Map(setnames,index_map[[x]],nams[[x]] )
lapply(seq(length(index_map)),fun)
```

Find below the part of the code where I experience an error. This is a valid format if index_map is a unique list (without the variables x). I aim to merge as per index of index_list. When attempting to do this however I get promted with the following error.

```
for (index in index_map)
fun <- function (x) merge (values[[x]] , index , by = names (index_map[[x]]) [1])
lapply (seq(length(index_map)),fun) 

Error in setkeyv(copy(y), by) : 
Column 'V1' is type 'list' which is not supported as a key column type, currently.
```

My understanding is that I fail to adecuadly instruct the loop to iterate over the two sublists that form index map. My aim is to be able to map the indexes in input_list that result in total_value. I have gone over other posts where loops are substituted by embeded functions however I fail to be able to instruct properly if this is the adequate format. Would you happen to know how could I instruct for this.

Answer (score 0):

`sapply(values[[1]])` should show that column `V1` is type `list`.  Type `list` means that each cell in the column can be anything; e.g. vectors of varying length, other embedded data.table's, any R object, functions, etc.

Have a look at that column and see if it really should be type `list`.  Probably it should be a `vector`; e.g. `integer`, `numeric` or `character` vector. If so, do `DT[,V1:=unlist(V1)]` on it. Ideally, avoid creating the `list` column in the first place.  The `list` type is useful for value columns but not really for join columns.